# Swift NotificationCenter remove observer quickest way

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am adding a number of observers in my `viewController` -- `applicationWillResignActive`, `applicationDidEnterBackground`, and many others. I want to remove `self` as observer to all registered notifications in one line. My question is whether the following line is enough to do that, or are there issues with this code?

```
deinit {
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: In iOS 11 above this is required code. But when your purpose competes of observing you can remove that specific observer will also help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

@Sh_Khan is right:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

You can get even further, as mentioned in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver#discussion):

> If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you don't need to unregister an observer in its dealloc method.

Comment: So if your app targets iOS 9.0 and later, we don't need to remove the Observers at all?

Unregister = removeObserver?

Answer (score 15):

So I'm working with this in an app right now and the answer might not be as straightforward.

In the documentation, it does state that for iOS 9 and above you are no longer required to explicitly remove the observer in the deinit/dealloc methods for objects. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver

However, it appears that this is only true for selector based notification observers. I'll be referencing this blog post: https://oleb.net/blog/2018/01/notificationcenter-removeobserver/.

If you are using block based observers  you must still manually remove the observers.

```swift
addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)
```

The best general way to do this is to capture the tokens in an array, append them when you add the observer and use them for removal when you deinit/dealloc or otherwise need to remove observer behavior for your object.

**in your VC/object properties create an array to store observer 'tokens'**

```swift
var notifObservers = [NSObjectProtocol]()
```

**Register for a block based notification by capturing the function return object and storing it as a token**

```swift
let observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: , object: , queue:) { [weak self] notification in
    // do a thing here
}
notifObservers.append(observer)
```

**Removal**

```swift
for observer in notifObservers {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
}
notifObservers.removeAll()
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer to save my day!  Thanks bro!

Answer (score 10):

Yes

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

this line is sufficient to remove the vc observation as long as all are added with

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver
```