# Passing Continuous Data (like Heart Rate) from ViewController to Another ViewController

Tags: swift, uicontainerview, heartrate

I am working on a Fitness app that gets data from Bluetooth Sensors (Heart Rate) and this data is a continuous stream of data.

My current implementation to show the data is to have both the Bluetooth Manager and the Display in the same view controller. I am looking to learn to decouple them (eg: using container view) but all the tutorials and SO pages I've seen on passing data from one VC to another VC (prepareForSegue and notification.Observer) looks like it's catered to passing simple 1 shot data/variables.

Question:

1. How do I pass continuous data from one VC to another VC?

Edit: [Passing data from ContainerView to UIPageViewController and then it's connected ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65493511/14414215) this question where I'm having trouble to even pass 1 simple variable hence I'm thinking how to even pass continuous data.

Comment: “looks like it's catered to passing simple 1 shot data/variables” Not at all. A notification is a publish and subscribe mechanism. Generalizing still further, Combine framework sounds perfect for this.

Comment: @matt thanks. I will explore tho combine framework looks to be a massive learning.

Comment: Agreed, but totally worth it. I’ve written an equally massive tutorial: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/